# How can i send a wave file from a client to a server using socket

Tags: python, sockets, wave

So im trying to send a saved wave file from a client to a server with socket however every attempt at doing it fails, the closest ive got is this:

```
#Server.py
requests = 0
while True:
    wavfile = open(str(requests)+str(addr)+".wav", "wb")
    while True:
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        requests = requests+1
        wavefile.write(data) 

#Client.py
bytes = open("senddata", "rb")
networkmanager.send(bytes.encode())
```

the error with this code is "AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'encode'" so is there anyway to fix this?, and im using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using "read-binary" mode, there's no need to encode bytes before sending.

And you should read the file to get bytes instead of BufferedReader.

```
bytes = open("senddata", "rb").read()
networkmanager.send(bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `read` to read bytes, and `sendall` to send the bytes to the server:

```
bytes = open("senddata", "rb")
networkmanager.sendall(bytes.read())
```